# how to use callback() with python

Tags: ros, callback, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

can anyone explain how to use callback in writing a subscriber? the tutorial uses callback(data),but what it data? what content dose it have? thank you very much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/303105/how-to-use-callback()-with-python/) by [lanlan](https://answers.ros.org/users/37449/lanlan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2018-09-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`data`  is just the variable name for the message that is passed in. You could name it `msg`, `foo` or `whateveryoulike`.

The content of it depends on the message type defined in the according instantiation of the subscriber. In [the tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29) this is `rospy.Subscriber("chatter", String, callback)` type is `std_msgs::String` (check the import statements).
You can find the data fields of ROS messages on the docs pages, e.g. [here](http://docs.ros.org/api/std_msgs/html/msg/String.html) or using `rosmsg show PKG MSG`.

---

**EDIT**

Well the first data in `callback(data)` is a ROS message, so if the ROS message is an `std_msgs/Int16`, `data` refers to that. However, this is actually a class and the actual `int16` is found in the `data.data` member. Again, the first `data` is just a name, the second one is the variable of the `std_msgs/Int16` which is "hardcoded".

As a more intuitive example, as it gets rid of this double `data` thing is e.g. [std_msgs/ColorRGBA](http://docs.ros.org/api/std_msgs/html/msg/ColorRGBA.html). `data` is the full message and you can access the respective field `r`, `g`, `b` and `a` via `data.r`, `data.g` and so on...

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lanlan](https://answers.ros.org/users/37449/lanlan/) on 2018-09-12**:
so if the message is int16, than the data will be exactly the int16? just the same as the message?

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-09-12**:
see edit above

**Comment by [lanlan](https://answers.ros.org/users/37449/lanlan/) on 2018-09-12**:
understand， thank you!

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-09-13**:
@lanlan if this answered your question, please check the answer as correct by clicking the check-mark on the left...